# I am trying to add a QrCode to my PDF but I am getting IOError

Tags: python, reportlab

I am trying to add a QrCode to my PDF using Reportlab but I am getting an IOerror. I have successfully appended my barcode before but the QrCode seems to be a bit trickier.

This is my QrCode Code:

```
def get_QRcode(self,inventory):
    receipt = str(inventory.identifier)
    qr_code = qr.QrCodeWidget(receipt)
    bounds = qr_code.getBounds()
    width = bounds[2] - bounds[1]
    height = bounds[3] - bounds[1]
    d = Drawing(45,45, transform = [45./width,0,0,45./height,0,0])
    d.add(qr_code)
    filename = tempfile.mkstemp()[1] + '.png'
    d.save(filename)


    return filename
```

Here is my append of QrCode:

`parts.append(Image(self.qrCode, width=.15* 0.35 *inch, height=.2*.25*inch))`

After trying to run this I get :

```
IOError at /inventories/download_tag/2525/
Cannot open resource "/tmp/tmpUf7ASf.png"
fileName='/tmp/tmpUf7ASf.png' identity=[ImageReader@0x7f6665819490 filename='/tmp/tmpUf7ASf.png']
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you

EDIT: Here is a snippet that appends my barcode and currently attempting to append a QRCode

```
def get_pdf_flows(self):
        sku = self.sku_name 
        sku =  sku + " ({0})".format(self.num_cases) if self.num_cases else sku
        sku = Paragraph(sku, self.sku_style)
        grower_detail = self.get_grower_detail()

        col1, col2 = self.get_table_rows()

        parts = []
        parts.append(Spacer(1, 30))
        parts.append(sku)
        parts.append(Spacer(1, 5))
        parts.append(Image(self.barcode_file, width=.15* 0.35 *inch, height=.2*.25*inch))
        parts.append(self.qrCode)
        parts.append(grower_detail)
        parts.append(Spacer(1, 5))
        t1 = Table(col1,colWidths='*')
        t2 = Table(col2,colWidths='*')
        data = [[t1, t2]]
        if self.foodhub.company_name== "Harvest Santa Barbara":
            parts.append(Table(data, colWidths=(1.75*inch, 2.25*inch)))
        return parts

    def get_doc(self):
        buff = StringIO.StringIO()
        doc = SimpleDocTemplate(buff, pagesize=(4*inch, 3*inch), rightMargin=0, leftMargin=0, topMargin=1*mm, bottomMargin=0)
        return doc, buff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can share how I have done it, but my implementation is to draw it directly on the canvas, then I add it in the footnote on the document template. Your method is to create a png and then add it (I do a similar thing with a graph object, but then I use pdfrw, which is a nice addin, I struggled a bit with write-access to folders when I started out). See if below works out for you.

```
from reportlab.lib.units import mm, cm
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.graphics.barcode import qr, code128
from reportlab.graphics.shapes import Drawing
from reportlab.platypus import Table, TableStyle
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate
from reportlab.lib import colors

def func(canvas, doc):
    canvas.saveState()

    # draw a QR code
    receipt = str(f'hello')
    qr_code = qr.QrCodeWidget(f'{receipt}')
    bounds = qr_code.getBounds()
    width = bounds[2] - bounds[0]
    height = bounds[3] - bounds[1]
    d = Drawing(60, 60, transform=[60. / width, 0, 0, 60. / height, 0, 0])
    d.add(qr_code)
    d.drawOn(canvas, 1.77 * cm, 259.55 * mm)

    #Draw Bar code
    canvas.setFillColor(colors.black)
    barcode = code128.Code128(receipt, barWidth=0.17 * mm, barHeight=5 * mm, ratio=2.75, humanReadable=1)
    barcode.drawOn(canvas, 5.95 * cm, 259.55 * mm)
    canvas.restoreState()

    return func
#
def create_pdf():
    story = []
    data = [['Data1', 'Data2', 'Data3', 'Data4', 'Data5', 'Data6'],
            ['0.2', '-0.1', '0', '0', '-0.5', '0.6']]

    colwidths = (50)
    rowheights = (10)

    t = Table(data, colwidths, rowheights)

    GRID_STYLE = TableStyle(
        [('FONTSIZE', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 5),
         ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.5, colors.black),
         ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'CENTER'),
         ('LEFTPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
         ('RIGHTPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
         ('TOPPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
         ('BOTTOMPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
         ('FONTNAME', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'Helvetica'),
         ('SIZE', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 7),
         ('LEADING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 8.2),
         ]
    )

    t.setStyle(GRID_STYLE)
    story.append(t)

    doc = SimpleDocTemplate('mydoc.pdf', pagesize=A4, topMargin=50)
    doc.build(story, onFirstPage=func)

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_pdf()  # Printing the pdf
```

Comment: Hey @Jaco I am having trouble implementing your solution. As the pdf.py file I am working with is appending images, spacers and details onto a page. This way would mean I am trying to append a Pdf canvas onto a pdf? I am also very new to working with reportlabs

Comment: I added a complete example, should work. Yes, the other method prints a small pdf as a picture and add it.

Comment: It works when I run it separately! So now I am having issues adding this to my current code. Currently I have a barcode sitting on the file and I would like the QR code next to it. (See EDIT) @Jaco

Comment: You could just add more code into the section that now holds the QR code, see my amended example, I have now added the BarCode to the right of QR Code. Please note that Reportlab uses two different methods, 1. Drawing directly on the canvas, and 2. Using Platypus, which is a simplified way to construct the document. You can mix them, you don't need to create a "flowable" of the qr and bar code to put into platypus to make it work, you could paint it directly on the "paper".